# Как восстановить удаленную таблицу innodb из ibdata1?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, innodb, восстановление

По невнимательности потер через *phpmyadmin* нужную таблицу. Есть вероятность, что нужные данные сохранились в ibdata1. Как оттуда вытянуть данные?

*Работаю с БД в сборке XAMPP под Windows.*

Comment: а полная резервная копия до этого снималась? журнал транзакций велся? можно попробовать накатить на сохраненную копию журнал до определенной транзакции. Сам этим не занимался, в общих чертах только представление имею. В [этой книжке](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do) что-то подобное рассматривается

Comment: Если б снималась, вопрос о восстановлении не стоял бы. Это была работа по анализу данных - я чистил сырые данные, докидывая необходимую информацию. И как-то не глядя потер все к чертям вместе с реально ненужными таблицами.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы удалили базу данных через phpMyAdmin, т.е. штатным запросом `DROP TABLE`, то вероятность того, что что-то осталось в ibdata1 практически нулевая. Особенно, если у вас не нагруженная база данных и изменения из журнала транзакций практически сразу применяются к табличному пространству в ibdata1. Данные и индексы в в ibdata1 остаются, если вы случайно потрете frm-файл с определением таблицы в каталоге данных. Тогда, создав аналогичный frm-файл можно получить доступ к таблице в табличном пространстве (правда создать его та еще задачка, так как MySQL будет считать, что таблица существует и не будет давать его создавать штатными средствами). Если же таблица удалена SQL-запросом, если у вас не было резервных копий или не были включены бинарные логи - шансов восстановить таблицу нет.